# Dropping a table based on data within it

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've taken over a project where the previous developer used a SQLite database to store **two *tables* per user**. We have about 70k tables right now, which is now causing crashing/inconsistencies with the software.

This is a discord bot, but not all users use the bot. So some of them have a balance of 0.

The obvious choice is to refactor into one table (as it should be...) but in the mean time I'd like to do a temporary measure to hopefully stop the issues we're having:

Drop any table where the user has 0 balance.

I haven't been able to find any way to do this. I found I can select all tables and thei

1. I can't DROP on a condition
2. I tried doing: `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name LIKE 'myBalance_%' AND (SELECT myBalance FROM name WHERE myBalance = 0);` to no avail (syntax error, can't access `name`)

I have sort of limited SQL knowledge and haven't had any luck googling.

Comment: SQLite is intended to be used embedded with a program. Write a program to query the names of the tables, then query each table for the balance and drop those which are 0.

Comment: @Schwern Huh.. Didn't really think about it like that. I'll give it a try.